# What is the disadvantage if I use objects on the stack instead of on the heap in factory pattern?

Tags: c++, factory

CPP codes are as follows：

```
Operation* OperationFactory:: CreateOperation(char opr) {
OperationAdd resultAdd;
OperationSub resultSub;
OperationMul resultMul;
OperationDiv resultDiv;
switch (opr) {
case '+':
    return &resultAdd;
case '-':
    return &resultSub;
case '*':
    return &resultMul;
case '/':
    return &resultDiv;
default:
    break;
}}
```

I find that there are some errors when I try to change the fields of objects created by this factory.

Comment: You are retuning a dangling pointer. The pointer points to a local object that's destroyed when the function ends. In general, prefer to return by value. If you need pointers use smart pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointers your return are useless once the function returns. Similar problem in simpler code:

```
int* dont_do_this(){
    int x = 0;
    return &x;
}
```

`x` no longer exists once the function returned and you have a dangling pointer. Dereferencing it causes undefined behavior.

It can be fixed by making `x` `static`:

```
int* maybe_do_this() {
    static int x = 0;
    return &x;
}
```

Now `x` persists between function calls. However, even if you fix that your "factory" will always return pointers to the same objects. If that is what you want, you wouldn't really need a factory in the first place. A factory is expected to create instances and return them:

```
std::unique_ptr<Operation> OperationFactory:: CreateOperation(char opr) {
    switch (opr) {
        case '+':
            return std::make_unique<OperationAdd>();
        case '-':
            return std::make_unique<OperationSub>();
        // ...
        default:
            return std::make_unique<OperationDefault>();
    }
}
```

Also you need to take care to return something on all branches and you should actually use smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Don't teach new programmers to use raw memory allocation please. `make_unique` is a much better match.

Comment: @MikeVine fixed

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

You should return a pointer to a heap allocated object because if you return a pointer to stack allocated object in the function's scope, the object pointed to by the pointer will be destroyed and the use of that pointer will cause an access violation!

Hope that helped you out!

I would suggest using a `std::unique_ptr<>` or a custom type that manages the destruction of the object because if the client doesn't free that memory, you might cause a memory leak!